# Universal deep link for iOS 9

Tags: xcode, ios9, deep-linking, custom-url, ios-universal-links

I would like to implement universal deep links for our apps. One of the requirement from the Apple is that apple-site-association file has to be on HTTPS web server. Is it just that or whole website needs to be https.

Ref: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016308-CH12

Comment: check full documentation here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35609667/how-to-support-universal-links-in-ios-app-and-setup-server-for-it/35609668#35609668

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've implemented universal links recently, and here are some points:

- Your `apple-app-site-association` file should be accessible through https. No other way around this.
- If your site is http only, then you have to sign the `apple-app-site-association` file. Using the same certificates that are used for the https `apple-app-site-association` file access.
- If your site is fully https, then you don't have to sign the `apple-app-site-association` file, you can just upload it as is.

I know I've said `apple-app-site-association` too often :), but I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding. I will try what you have mentioned.